# How to populate Plist date to Tableview

Tags: objective-c

I created a `plist` for `tableview`, but I don't know how to populate the `plist` in to Xcode (using objective c), nor my `plist` date.

```
<plist version="1.0">    
<dict>    
    <key>Robert Mitchall</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>8.png</string>    
        <string>Hey dude!</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Carrie Ronald</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>7.png</string>    
        <string>Lets have a coffe!</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Alicia Donnoven</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>10.png</string>    
        <string>Are you around?</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Kenny Jonnes</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>6.png</string>    
        <string>About our discussion.</string>    
    </array>    
</dict>    
</plist>
```

then, I add this code in my view `controller.m`, for populating.

```
@interface ViewController ()    
{    
    NSArray *content;    
}

-(NSArray *)content    
    {    
        if (!_content) {    
            _content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]];    
        }    
        return _content;    
    }    


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{        
return [self.content count];    
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
 {        
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";        
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    

cell.textLabel.text    = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"item 0"];        

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"item 1"];    
return cell;    
}
```

I did't get any output showing that I had an error.

[image: Results]

Actually, I need the main page in table view date to look like it does in this image.

[image: Preferred]

Comment: what's the error then, where is it from - help us to help you

Comment: sorry friend, i had "invalid argument type ' NSArray' to unary expression..in this part  -(NSArray *)content{

Comment: -(NSArray *)content    
    {    
        if (!_content) {    
            _content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]];    
        }    
        return _content;    
    }                                                       - error on this section

Comment: Am beginning stage for learning iOS.thats why i could't clear the error.

Comment: you don't appear to have defined `_content`, is there a reason you're not using a property ?

Comment: i set properties in view controller.h   as                                                                @property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *content;                                                         and also in view controller.m file i set                                                                   synthesize content = _content; .. Friend wain can you help me where i can defined this? _content

Comment: remove the synthesise, you don't need it, also remove the instance variables in the .m file, you don't need them

Comment: How to use  dictionary instead of plist data, using as the same plist data above.

Comment: i think it should be an array and you should change your plist to be an array of dictionaries. a dictionary of arrays can work but is messy

Comment: thanks friend wain..  i will try this method.

Comment: The content of the property list file is a dictionary, not an array

Answer (score 0):

Because the root node in your plist is a `<dict>`.

Update:

ViewController:

```
- (NSArray *)content {
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
    return _content;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.content count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text    = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
}
```

Property List.plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>8.png</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Hey dude!</string>
        </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>7.png</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Lets have a coffe!</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>10.png</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>Are you around?</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>image</key>
        <string>6.png</string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string>About our discussion.</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Update:

As far as I understand "how to use Dictionary (code) instead of Plist for about task", i modify the code.

```
<plist version="1.0">    
<dict>    
    <key>Robert Mitchall</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>8.png</string>    
        <string>Hey dude!</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Carrie Ronald</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>7.png</string>    
        <string>Lets have a coffe!</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Alicia Donnoven</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>10.png</string>    
        <string>Are you around?</string>    
    </array>    
    <key>Kenny Jonnes</key>    
    <array>    
        <string>6.png</string>    
        <string>About our discussion.</string>    
    </array>    
</dict>    
</plist>   


- (NSDictionary *)content {
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
    return _content;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.content count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.content.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *detailArray = [self.content.allValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [detailArray objectAtIndex:1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Friends, i don't know what the code should i need to write in cellForRowAtIndexPath for the above Plist data, to populate into tableview. help me please

Comment: i can't get any output this the above discussion screenshot (its displaying empty data row). help me friends

Comment: @BalajiM Try my code now.I modify the content in your plist.And the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` also changed.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Can you give me example of how to use Dictionary (code) instead of Plist for about task.

Comment: Tony, i tried to the code in my project but i had error like this.                Property 'allKeys' not found on object of type 'NSArray.                    Property 'allValues' not found on object of type 'NSArray '

Comment: and my property  -  @property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *allKeys, *allValues;

Comment: Your property should be `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *content;`

Comment: thanks tony,  i added property like you said, another help how to get dictionary key value to array value.

Comment: my dictionary name is _content  & i set path.                                                                                                        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];                                                                                                                                                    _content = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];                                                                                                                                 NSLog(@"%@", _content)